# Pushwoosh alert

Tags: iphone, push-notification, pushwoosh

I have iPhone messaging app and I have to use push notifications. 
Like iMessage, I'd like to have the alert when the app is in background. Innstead I'd like to not have the alert when the app is open, I'd like only to handle the notification to show the new messages. Can you help me? Thanks.

Comment: Did you read any documentation about Push notifications on iOS, because all your question are answered here: https://developer.apple.com/notifications/

Comment: Ok but I don't understand, can you explain to me?

Comment: Since I don't know what part you do not understand my answer will be too big for StackOverflow. I suggest you use google to search from some tutorials.

Comment: The question is exactly what I have write in this question

Comment: That is way too broad, also you should try to solve the issue your self before posting it where.

Comment: I try to solve the issue and I have a specific problem: hide the alert when a push arrives. This is not the way to help to solve a problem. If you don't know the answer or you don't want to answer, simply don't answer. I don't understand this attitude.

Comment: Well just to inform you, there is no alert dialog shown when you app is in the foreground. So there is nothing to hide. Also please read the [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I a library you use show the dialog then many you might want to not use that library or look if you can disable it in the documentation of that library.